# What function can I use to query all records with NULL values in DolphinDB?

Tags: null, dolphindb

My table is:

```
x1 = 1 NULL 2 NULL NULL
x2 = 1 NULL NULL 3 4
x3 = 3 NULL 3 4 5
t = table(x1 ,x2 ,x3)
```

| x1 | x2 | x3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
|  |  |  |
| 2 |  | 3 |
|  | 3 | 4 |
|  | 4 | 5 |

I want to keep all the records that have null values in the table. I thought it may be a problem that can be handled by some SQL statement. What clause or function in DolphinDB to choose?

Answer (score 1):

You can try function `each`:

```
x1 = 1 NULL 2 NULL NULL
x2 = 1 NULL NULL 3 4
x3 = 3 NULL 3 4 5
t = table(x1 ,x2 ,x3)
 
t[each(isNull, t.values()).rowOr()]
```

The result is
[image]